# How to install FFTW-2.1.5 on an M1 MacBook Pro?

Tags: c, build, apple-m1, fftw

I'm trying to install fftw-2.1.5 as it is required by the GADGET3 code version I need to use. I had no issues building it on my Linux machine (running Ubuntu 22.04), but on my M1 MacBook Pro (running macOS Monterey 12.4) it crashes at the configure step.

Running:

```
./configure --prefix=path/to/local/install \
            --enable-mpi \
            --enable-type-prefix \ 
            --with-gcc
```

I got the following error message:

```
checking build system type... configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub -apple-darwin21.5.0 failed
```

It seems that the configure script is not properly parsing the details of the MacBook, hence it crashes before testing the rest of the dependencies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am fairly new to macOS and I have never had to use *autotools* before.

I found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/pemsley/coot/issues/33#issuecomment-1086901325), so credits to the people that documented it there. I am unsure if **all** the following steps are required but they certainly solved my issue:

1. I renamed *configure.in* to *configure.ac*
2. I downloaded and applied all the patches from this [website](https://sources.debian.org/patches/fftw/2.1.5-6/). I simply copied the text of each patch into new files *patch_filename* and ran `$ patch < patch_filename` in the main fftw-2.1.5 directory. As I renamed *configure.in* to *configure.ac*, when applying patch *05_ac_define_syntax.diff* it will prompt the user to specify the path to the file to patch, i.e. *configure.ac*.
3. *(OPTIONAL)* I also needed OpenMP support so additionally I needed to modify lines 249, 251, 253, 255 and 257 so that the variables *omp_enabler* and *CFLAGS* read as `omp_enabler="$CC -fopenmp"` and `CFLAGS="$save_CFLAGS -fopenmp"`, where CC=gcc in my case.
4. I ran `$ autoupdate` followed by `$ autoreconf -vfi` in the main fftw-2.1.5 directory.
5. I ran the configure script with the desired flags, e.g. for double precision + MPI support:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=path/to/local/install \
              --enable-mpi \
              --enable-type-prefix \
              --with-gcc \
              LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/lib \
              CFLAGS=-I/opt/hombrew/include
```

6. Finally, the standard `make` into `make check` and `make install` did the trick